# iOS digital number from different table view cell is not aligned as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, alignment

I have a label called dollarLabel in custom table view cell, and set its auto layout constraints and appearance as following code snippets:

```
// Dollar label constraint.
dollarLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

dollarLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
dollarLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subCategoryLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
dollarLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
dollarLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
dollarLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

// Dollar label appearance.
dollarLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.right
dollarLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
dollarLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

And the cells are shown as below:

[image]

I’m wondering why the dollar symbol of the third row is not aligned as the first and the second dollar symbol?
I set its textAlignment property to NSTextAlignment.right, and I expect that the three dollar symbol should be aligned vertically when the digital number have the same length.

What’s going wrong about my code?
Many thanks!

Comment: You just need to use a fixed width font or monospacedDigitSystemFont. try something like this: `dollarLabel.font = .monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)`

Comment: @LeoDabus It works! Thanks!